# Retrofit optional and required fields

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

When using Retrofit, I know you can use `@FieldMap Map<String, String> options` to specify optional queries.

Say that I have a api call that had 2 required fields and 3 optional fields.

How would I format these calls?

Would it be something like

```
Call<Response> getStuff(@Query("user_id") String userId, @Query("password") String password, @FieldMap Map<String, String> options)
```

or would the entire thing be a single @FieldMap like:

`Call<Response> getStuff(@FieldMap Map<String, String> options)`

and with this option would you just fill in the required fields and then use `null` for the optionals?

Comment: Pls read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36634926/how-to-handle-null-param-values-in-retrofit/36640325#36640325

Answer (score 77, accepted):

`@FieldMap` and `@Query` params both support optional fields. As you mentioned, simply pass `null` if you don't want to pass a value.

Comment: So to confirm, it would be best to just have the the call be a single `@FieldMap Map<String, String>` with null values where needed?

Comment: I generally recommend using explicit `@Query` fields as they can be used to self-document endpoints, but a `@FieldMap` should also do the job.

Comment: beware! null values aren't allowed in @FieldMap in Retrofit2

Answer (score 27):

I have stuck in the question several hours and finally resolve the question.

I' ll use Kotlin to answer the question.

As @Ryan said, you can also just pass `null` as the value in Kotlin:

```
fun getStuff(@Query("user_id") userId: String? = null ,
                 @Query("password") password: String? = null,
                 @FieldMap options: Map<String, String>? = null): Call<Response>
```

If you have a optional fields like `@Query("page") int page` in Java, there is something that you should keep in mind:

In Java, you can’t pass null for primitive data types like `int`, `float`, `long`, etc.

Instead, use `Integer`, `Float`, `Long`, etc and the compiler won’t be grumpy.

So the correct answer is: `@Query("page") Integer page`.

And in Kotlin, you can’t pass null for primitive data types like `Int`, `Float`, `Long`, etc.

Using `Int?` instead of `Int` and Retrofit will ignore them while assembling the request.

This is because while Kotlin compile on the JVM, non-nullable values of this type are represented as values of the primitive type `int`, nullable value like `Int?` is a boxed Type.

So in Kotlin, a nullable Int Int? can solve this question.

For more information about Kotlin primitive, see: [What is the difference between Int and Integer in Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46274888/what-is-the-difference-between-int-and-integer-in-kotlin)

I hope it helped somebody also.

Answer (score 0):

Retrofit2 (unlike Retrofit1) does not accept null values in `@FiledMap` (throws exception). 
Null-values passed to `@Field`/`@Query` params are ignored (do not appear in http-request)

Answer (score 0):

yes ryan said it correct.

in java your call example will be:

```
Call<Response> getStuff(null,null,@FieldMap Map<String, String> options);
```

Remember this will work perfectly with "String"
if you want to keep "int" or "float" as optional, don't use primitive data types like int, float, long, etc. Instead, use Integer, Float, Long, etc
so your example with optional integer and float will be:

```
Call<Response> getStuff(@Query("user_id") Integer userId, @Query("password") Float password, @FieldMap Map<String, String> options);
```

this syntax will take skip Integer values (handle it on server side, if needed).

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using custom interceptors in okhttp client.

```
  val NULL_STRING = "null"
class QueryParamInterceptor : Interceptor {
    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        val request = chain.request()

        val urlBuilder = request.url.newBuilder()

        for (queryName in request.url.queryParameterNames) {
            val queryValue = request.url.queryParameter(queryName)

            if (queryValue?.toLowerCase() == NULL_STRING) {
              
                urlBuilder.removeAllQueryParameters(queryName)
                continue
            }
           

        }

        Log.d("TAG", "intercept: ${urlBuilder.build()}")
        val newRequest = request.newBuilder()
            .url(urlBuilder.build())
            .build()

        return chain.proceed(newRequest)
    }
}
```

The code above parses each URL and whenever it finds null it removes from the URL. You can setup this in OkHttp Client using like the below code.

```
val httpClient: OkHttpClient.Builder =
                OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor)
                    .addInterceptor(QueryParamInterceptor())
```

The next time when you make API calls it will automatically remove all the null query parameters from the URL.