# What is the difference between Int and Integer in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I have tried using Int and Integer types in Kotlin. Although I don't see any difference.
Is there a difference between Int and Integer types in Kotlin? Or are they the same?

Comment: Related: https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/relationship-between-classes-like-kotlin-int-and-java-integer-and-int-primitive/671

Answer (score 50, accepted):

`Int` is a Kotlin Class derived from `Number`.  [See doc](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-int/index.html#int)

> [Int] Represents a 32-bit signed integer. On the JVM, non-nullable values of
>   this type are represented as values of the primitive type int.

`Integer` is a Java Class.

If you were to search the Kotlin spec for "Integer", there is no Kotlin `Integer` type.

If you use the expression `is Integer` in IntelliJ, the IDE warns...

> This type shouldn't be used in Kotlin, use Int instead.

`Integer` will interoperate well with Kotlin Int, but they do have some subtle differences in behavior, for example:

```
val one: Integer = 1 // error: "The integer literal does not conform to the expected type Integer"
val two: Integer = Integer(2) // compiles
val three: Int = Int(3) // does not compile
val four: Int = 4 // compiles
```

In Java, there are times where you need to explicitly "box" an integer as an object.  In Kotlin only Nullable integers (`Int?`) are boxed.  Explicitly trying to box a non-nullable integer will give a compiler error:

```
val three: Int = Int(3) // error: "Cannot access '<init>': it is private in 'Int'
val four: Any = 4 // implicit boxing compiles (or is it really boxed?)
```

But `Int` and `Integer` (`java.lang.Integer`) will be treated the same most of the time.

```
when(four) {
    is Int -> println("is Int")
    is Integer -> println("is Integer")
    else -> println("is other")
} //prints "is Int"
when(four) {
    is Integer -> println("is Integer")
    is Int -> println("is Int")
    else -> println("is other")
} //prints "is Integer"
```

Comment: A non-nullable `Int` will be boxed when used with generics. For example, `List<Int>` will contain boxed integers.

Answer (score 18):

A `Int` is a primitive Type. This is equivalent to JVM int.

A nullable Int `Int?` is a boxed Type. This is equivalent to `java.lang.Integer`.

Comment: Can you add a reference since I couldn't find a clue from the documentation?

Answer (score 8):

Just have a look at https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html#representation

> On the Java platform, numbers are physically stored as JVM primitive
>   types, unless we need a nullable number reference (e.g. Int?) or
>   generics are involved. In the latter cases numbers are boxed.

That means, that `Int` is represented as primitive `int`. Only in cases when nullability or generics are involved, the backing Wrapper Type `Integer` must be used. 
If you use `Integer` from the beginning, you always work with the wrapper type and never with the primitive `int`.